# Parse Analytics REST API: retrieve Daily Active Installation

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to get Daily Active Installation data from parse Analytics. However, Analytics API is poorly documented ( https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#analytics ).

I just want to do get list recent few days of Daily Active Installation data. If anyone tried to get data from Analytics please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one possible way... You can query "installations" count and limit the query by "updatedAt" value. I hope that object is updated each time app is started.

```
curl -X GET
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xx...xx"
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: xx...xx"
'https://api.parse.com/1/installations/?count=1&limit=0&where={"updatedAt":{"$gte":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-10-12T00:00:00.0Z"}}}'
```